# Find rows by matching pair values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

i Have a following dataframe

| A-Party | B-Party | Duration | Call Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 2 | In |
| B | A | 2 | out |
| B | A | 3 | in |
| c | B | 10 | in |
| B | c | 10 | out |

The desired output is

| A-Party | B-Party | Duration | Call Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 2 | In |
| B | A | 2 | out |
| c | B | 10 | in |
| B | c | 10 | out |

i want to match to get rows in which different rows have same pair values of columns A-Party and B-Party(like first two rows have pair (A,B) and (B,A)) as well their Duration values shoud match and Call Type should be opposite.Provide me the efficient solution for this.

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code?

Comment: maybe you should convert columns A-Party and B-Party to single column with `set()` of values. This way you can compare (or `.groupby()`) because `set(["A", "B"]) == set(["B", "A"])`